# Subdomain in react router

Tags: reactjs, subdomain, react-router

I'd like to setup react router for use with subdomains. I'm unsure where the logic for subdomain proxying should lie.

I want:

`roxy.coolestblog.com/profile` to route to `coolestblog.com/roxy/profile`
`mohammed.coolestblog.com/profile` to route to `coolestblog.com/mohammed/profile`
`benben.coolestblog.com/profile` to route to `coolestblog.com/benben/profile`

another use case:

`en.coolestblog.com/some-article` to route to `coolestblog.com/en/some-article`
`fr.coolestblog.com/un-article` to route to `coolestblog.com/fr/un-article`
`es.coolestblog.com/una-article` to route to `coolestblog.com/es/una-article`

I already have it working without the subdomain.

How can I achieve this so it works both on client and server?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? Looks like I have the same need...

Comment: If you found a solution, please share

Comment: Answered similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62459628/178043) in case its helpful

Comment: Did you find a solution for this @collinglass?

Answer (score 8):

While the browser history API limits our ability, we can interact directly with `window.location` in order to accomplish this.

Just before setting up your router, you can modify the URL by doing something like this:

```
let host = window.location.host;
let protocol = window.location.protocol;
let parts = host.split(".");
let subdomain = "";
// If we get more than 3 parts, then we have a subdomain
// INFO: This could be 4, if you have a co.uk TLD or something like that.
if (parts.length >= 3) {
  subdomain = parts[0];
  // Remove the subdomain from the parts list
  parts.splice(0, 1);
  // Set the location to the new url
  window.location = protocol + "//" + parts.join(".") + "/" + subdomain;
}
```

Of course, this has its caveats. For instance, if you do not know your host name explicitly, you cannot correctly determine if there is a subdomain or not. It does not make any assumptions about what the following URL should be, but it would be trivial to solve for that.

Comment: Does it have an advantage over getting it from cookies?