# React-router urls not working when manually typing in browser

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When I navigate between pages using the navbar and the buttons, the URL on the browser changes normally. But once I try to modify the URL manually, it does not work !

**Example 1**

- Step 1 : I open ***localhost:3000***
- Step 2 : I click on Athletes to go to ***localhost:3000/Athletes***
- Step 3 : I choose an athlete to go to ***localhost:3000/Athletes/2/AthleteSessions/***
- Step 4 : I change the URL manually to ***localhost:3000/Athletes*** then I choose an athlete, I'm redirected to ***localhost:3000/Athletes/2/AthleteSessions/*** fine until now, but when I modify the URL to put ***localhost:3000/Athletes/*** with **a slash** then I choose an athlete it does not work and I'm redirected to ***localhost:3000/Athletes/Athletes/2/AthleteSessions/***

**Example 2**

- Step 1, 2 and 3 are the same as the first example.
- Step 4 : I choose an AthleteSession to go to ***localhost:3000/Athletes/2/AthleteSessions/1/TrainingSession/*** it works fine, but when I try to go back to previous page by modifying manually the URL ***localhost:3000/Athletes/2/AthleteSessions*** then I choose an AthleteSession again, it does not work and I'm redirected to ***localhost:3000/Athletes/2/1/TrainingSession/***

**App.js**

```
import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

<Route path="/Athletes" exact component={Athletes} />
<Route path="/Athletes/:id/AthleteSessions" exact component={AthleteSessions} />
<Route path="/Athletes/:athleteId/AthleteSessions/:athleteSessionId/TrainingSession"
       exact component={AthleteTrainingSession} />
```

**Index.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

render( <Router> <App /> </Router>, document.getElementById("root") );
```

**Athletes.js**

```
onClick={() => {
  this.props.history.push({
    pathname:
      "Athletes/" + ath.AthleteId + "/AthleteSessions/",
  });
}}
```

**AthleteSessions.js**

```
passedAthleteId = this.props.match.params.id;

onClick={() => {
  this.props.history.push({
    pathname:
      athSess.AthleteSessionId + "/TrainingSession/",
  });
}}
```

Comment: Here are the instructions on how you create a StackOverflow snippet: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: I created a git repo with the code you need to see : https://github.com/Waelos/react-url-manual-modification

Comment: Thanks @AjeetShah :-)

Comment: I forked your repo and raised pull request. [Forked repo](https://github.com/ajeetshah/react-url-manual-modification). *solution-2* and solution-1**, there are 2 branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **current route** definition is **fine**:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route exact path="/Athletes" component={Athletes} />
    <Route
        exact
        path="/Athletes/:id/AthleteSessions"
        component={AthleteSessions}
    />
    <Route
        exact
        path="/Athletes/:athleteId/AthleteSessions/:athleteSessionId/TrainingSession"
        component={AthleteTrainingSession}
    />
</Switch>
```

But to go to any route you are **currently** doing [`history.push`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/Navigation.md) without **leading `/`**, and with a **trailing `/`** which **causes the problem**:

```
// FIRST (lets refer it first)
onClick={() => { 
    this.props.history.push({
    pathname:
        "Athletes/" + ath.AthleteId + "/AthleteSessions/",
    });
}}

// SECOND (lets refer it second)
onClick={() => {
    this.props.history.push({
    pathname:
        athSess.AthleteSessionId + "/TrainingSession/",
    });
}}
```

> `history.push('/hello')` takes from `localhost:3000/some/url` to `localhost:3000/hello` --> **Easy to understand**
>
> `history.push('hello')` takes from `localhost:3000/some/url` to `localhost:3000/some/hello` --> **Not so easy, so avoid**

So, everything is **working fine** as long as you are going to FIRST and SECOND using above `history.push` methods.

But **problems start** when you start manually **typing a URL** in the browser, sometimes with an **ending `/`** and sometimes without one.

---

### Solution 1:

Change your FIRST and SECOND to use **fully qualified urls** with leading `/` and no trailing `/`, trailing `/` isn't important anymore as we using full qualified urls. Also, see [Strict-Bool](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink/strict-bool):

```
// FIRST
onClick={() => { 
    this.props.history.push({
    pathname:
        "/Athletes/" + ath.AthleteId + "/AthleteSessions",
    });
}}

// SECOND
onClick={() => {
  this.props.history.push({
    pathname: `/Athletes/${this.props.match.params?.id}/AthleteSessions/${athSess.AthleteSessionId}/TrainingSession`,
  });
}}
```

As we are now using full qualified URLs, it will **work** perfectly but the code seems hard to manage as you will be **forming the full urls** at each `history push`.

---

### Solution 2:

SAME as Solution 1 but better code:

Define your routes using `paths` and `makePaths`:

```
export const paths = {
  Athletes: "/Athletes",
  AthleteSessions: "/Athletes/:id/AthleteSessions",
  AthleteTrainingSession:
    "/Athletes/:athleteId/AthleteSessions/:athleteSessionId/TrainingSession",
};

export const makePaths = {
  AthleteSessions: (id) => {
    return `/Athletes/${id}/AthleteSessions`;
  },
  AthleteTrainingSession: (athleteId, athleteSessionId) => {
    return `/Athletes/${athleteId}/AthleteSessions/${athleteSessionId}/TrainingSession`;
  },
};

// in JSX
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  <Route exact path={paths.Athletes} component={Athletes} />
  <Route exact path={paths.AthleteSessions} component={AthleteSessions} />
  <Route
    exact
    path={paths.AthleteTrainingSession}
    component={AthleteTrainingSession}
  />
</Switch>
```

And `history.push`:

```
// FIRST
onClick={() => {
  this.props.history.push({
    pathname: makePaths.AthleteSessions(ath.AthleteId),
  });
}}

// SECOND
onClick={() => {
  this.props.history.push({
    pathname: makePaths.AthleteTrainingSession(
      this.props.match.params?.id,
      athSess.AthleteSessionId
    ),
  });
}}
```

---

### Solution 3:

Do nested routing. See [nesting example in docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/nesting), [how to do nesting?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62024285/2873538) and [how to access URL Params i.e. `:id` in path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62055813/2873538).

---

I would recommend going with *Solution 2* but do read *Solution 3 (nesting)* and if / when possible go with that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file at the root of your website called staticwebapp.config.json.  The contents should be

```
{
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "/index.html"
  }
}
```

this will solve your issue.